# Rails, how to sort the array of active records by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

Hi there I have two arrays having different values of active records from same table but having different values, I want to combine them both and then sort them by `created_at`, but not getting any clue, I am stuck.
Please help.

Here is my code:

```
@find_user = EmployeeLeave.where(global_user_id: @allarray[i]).find(:all)
@all << @find_user
@find_referal_user = EmployeeLeave.where(referral_id: @allarray[i]).find(:all)
@all_entry << @find_referal_user
@total = @all + @all_entry
```

any thing is not working please help me to sort the `@total`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can sort an array by using sort_by.

In your case, you could do the following:

```
@total.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

**Update:**

- Remove @all << @find_user and @all_entry << @find_referal_user

  - Why? Because otherwise you will have an array with multiple arrays
- Replace @total with: @total = @find_user + @find_referal_user

  - Why? Because @total will now only consists of one merged array with all objects, ready to get sorted through .sort_by(&:created_at).

Comment: its giving "NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `created_at' for []:Array" fot this.

Comment: Peter: you were 3 seconds faster :)

Comment: I assume you have an array with multiple objects and each of these objects have a created_at field. In this case it should definitely work. Perhaps you can enlighten us with your array output.

Comment: here they are:-
[[], [#<EmployeeLeave id: 2, global_user_id: 1, referral_id: 6, is_half_day: false, leave_start_date: "2013-09-19 12:00:00", leave_end_date: "2013-09-24 12:00:00", subject: "rewewr", remark: "wewrewrewr", status: "Pending", tl_approval_status: "Unapproved", created_at: "2013-09-17 10:39:15", updated_at: "2013-09-17 10:39:21">], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] ]

Comment: Oh wait, you have multiple arrays within an array. First, you need to merge both array. Don't use all << find_user. Instead, just stick with total = all + all_entry. Now you will only have one merged array and you can use sort_by.

Comment: Small typo in my comment: Remove all << find_user and all_entry << find_referal_user. And use total = find_user + find_referal_user.

Comment: Also, use Array#flatten to flatten the array.

Comment: In the code I have written above I'm using that code inside a loop, so its over riding the previous values.

Answer (score 7):

You can always use the order method:

```
@total.order! 'created_at DESC'
```

Comment: yep, or `@total.order({ created_at: :desc })`, docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

Answer (score 5):

And if you need descending order just use `reverse`

```
@total.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in this way:

```
@total = EmployeeLeave.find(
  :all,
  :conditions => ["global_user_id = ? or referral_id = ?", @allarray[i], @allarray[i]],
  :order => "created_at ASC"
)
```

So it will find all `EmployeeLeave` whose `global_user_id` or `referral_id` eq `@allarray[i]` and sort the result by `created_at`.